# Android set selected background to list row after reload data?

Tags: android, listview

I have following issue: I have a `ListView`.If you click on a row, My list is reloaded and  a button is added on the  row. No Problem till now... but: After adding button i want the `ListView` (after its reload) to select the just edited (or added) row. I want selected row(the row on which button is  added) remain highlighted after reload list.

Any suggestion or sample code would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: when i click on row my listview is reloaded and a button is added on it now i want is that after adding that button the row should remain selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `setSelection(position)` ?
You might have to use the following code :

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(position);
    }
});
```

**Update :**
Try the XML attributes `android:listSelector` and `android:drawSelectorOnTop`(see the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3adrawSelectorOnTop)) to highlight the selected item.
If it does not work as you want, you can create a custom `Adapter` with an int attribute named selectedPosition, pass the position of the selected item to this `Adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in the method `OnItemClick`, and in the `Adapter`, change the `View` returned by `getView` if the position equals selectedPosition.

Comment: After changing the content of your `ListView`.

Comment: What does "select a row" mean in your case ?

Comment: when i click on row my listview is reloaded and a button is added on it now i want is that after adding that button the row should remain selected

Comment: My question was what is the effect you want for a selected a row ? Does it appear highlighted ? Because it's usually only when a row is clicked that it's highlighted.